# Make http(s) request where the GET request is dependent on the POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm currently working on a project in node where I'm supposed to first send a POST request and after that a GET request which is dependent on the response of the POST request. Do someone have any suggestion on how to go about this? I'm using axios and express. the asynchronous/synchronous thing is getting on my nerves.

My code

```
const express = require("express");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("Public"));

var url1 = "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/";
var url2 = "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/";
//POST
 var axios = require("axios");
 var data = JSON.stringify({
   purchase_country: "SE",
   purchase_currency: "SEK",
   locale: "sv-SE",
   order_amount: 50000,
   order_tax_amount: 4545,
   order_lines: [
     {
       type: "physical",
       reference: "19-402-USA",
       name: "Red T-Shirt",
       quantity: 5,
       quantity_unit: "pcs",
       unit_price: 10000,
       tax_rate: 1000,
       total_amount: 50000,
       total_discount_amount: 0,
       total_tax_amount: 4545,
     },
   ],
   merchant_urls: {
     checkout:
       "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/checkout?sid={checkout.order.id}",
     confirmation:
       "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/confirmation?sid={checkout.order.id}",
     push: "https://www.example.com/api/push",
   },
 });

 var config = {
   method: "post",
   url: url1,
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     Authorization:
       "",
   },
   data: data,
 };

 //GET
 var axios = require("axios");
 var data1 = "";

 var config1 = {
   method: "get",
   url:
     url2,
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     Authorization:
       "",
   },
   data: data1,
 };


 
 axios(config)
 .then(response => {
  
  return axios(config1)
 }).then(response => {
   
 })
 .catch(err => console.log(err))
  
   
app.listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you show none of your code, we can only answer conceptually.  Since promises are easiest to sequence using `async/await`, that is the model I chose to show you here:

```
async function someFunction() {

   const postResult = await axios.post(someUrl, someData);
   const getResult = await axios.get(someUrl2, {params: {can use postResult in here}});
   // further processing
   return something;
}

// call it like this
somefunction().then(finalResult => {
    console.log(finalResult);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

We could show more detail if you showed your actual code.

Comment: @jacoblarsson - Why did you accept this and then hours later unaccept it?  Why does this concept not work for you?